# How do you rate proposed LoRa joining scheme, pairing based encryption. Modified version of OTAA

Tags: encryption

I'm developing a protocol for private LoRa (Any RF by abstract) product, It consists of a gateway and a sensor node. I don't use LoRaWAN.
I want the user to dynamically 'pair/link' one to multiple sensor nodes to a gateway by pressing a button in both sides (Sensor node and Gateway).

I got suggestions to look at OTAA joining protocol, which is pretty much secured and doesn't share any keys on the air:

[image: OTAA joining procedure]

LoRaWAN consists of 3 nodes : End Device , Network Server , Application Server
While my architect consists of 2 nodes : End Device and Gateway (Network Server).

Because of the reduced number of nodes in protocol, I think don't need some elements of it.

But sticking to generate one Session Key as the common goal.

As I think, what's not needed:

- AppEUI
- DevNonce *
- NetSKey (What's needed is one key)

*: Pairing via push buttons would replace that, as I propose.

The proposed joining protocol remains Dev EUI as a unique key in the End Device(s). while a shared AppKey between the Gateway and End device(s).

After agreeing on a key, the sensor node sends encrypted data with agreed upon AppSKey, Gateway transmits the encrypted data to the cloud.

How do you analyze the proposed protocol ?
What are your suggestions ?